# Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined in FireStore Function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my Angular project I'm working with Google Cloud functions in Firebase for the first time and I'm having a problem in this line: `const userId = event.params.userId;`

**ERROR IN MY LOGS:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
>       at exports.firestoreEmail.functions.firestore.document.onCreate.event
>   (/user_code/index.js:16:32)
>       at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

If I do the following `const userId = "6j1lvREbZwFEfzzJxQg7";` it works perfectly fine.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp();

    const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
    const SENDGRID_API_KEY =
      "SECRET API KEY";

    const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
    sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
      .document("users/{userId}/followers/{followerId}")
      .onCreate(event => {
        const userId = event.params.userId;

        const db = admin.firestore();

        return db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(userId)
          .get()
          .then(doc => {
            const user = doc.data();

            const msg = {
              to: user.email,
              from: "hello@angularfirebase.com",
              subject: "New Follower",
              // text: `Hey ${toName}. You have a new follower!!! `,
              // html: `<strong>Hey ${toName}. You have a new follower!!!</strong>`,

              // custom templates
              templateId: "d-c66513d40f0e4b79845f63d598df5e07",
              substitutionWrappers: ["{{", "}}"],
              substitutions: {
                name: user.displayName
                // and other custom properties here
              }
            };

            return sgMail.send(msg);
          })
          .then(() => console.log("email sent!"))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      });
```

I have tried to change it to the following:

```
event.userId
user.userId
event.data().userId
```

Those didn't work.

Comment: can you console.log(event) and show the object please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events the onCreate event takes two parameters (event and context) so try changing your code to `.onCreate((event,context) => {...})` and you should be able to access userId via `context.params.userId`

Comment: wow! you are a genius!! thanks so much dude!! https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sendgrid-v3-nodejs-transactional-email-cloud-function/ I followed this tutorial and they didn't use context. I guess is not updated

Comment: @PatricioVargas Yes, your tutorial is not up to date and is not aligned with the changes that were introduced with Cloud Functions Version 1.0.0, see this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thank so much  Renaud!